# Re-placing a table in LibreOffice writer causes unwanted page break (huge gap)

Tags: libreoffice

I have an RTF document with two tables

```
table-1
table-2
```

I copied table-1 and pasted it under table-2, but I also got a page brake between them, which I didn't mean to have

**Now I have two separate pages:**

```
Page one contains table-1
Page two contains table-2
```

I find no way to to delete the huge gap of empty page between them (where my cursor is I hit <kbd>Delete</kbd> and nothing happens, and if I hit <kbd>Backspace</kbd> my cursor is moved to page-1, but **without the table**:

---

[image]

---

### My question

How to remove the unwanted page break between the two tables so both tables will appear on the same page (just one above the other)?

Comment: Off-topic comment, but I think that LibreOffice works best with its native ODF format. So, if possible, first "save as" any non-ODF file as ODF and work on the ODF version. Once done, save in the desired other format.

Comment: I suppose this is related to an issue with the automatic text flow. Pretty sure that the gap will be gone when you close and reopen the document, or when you perform some other actions that require recalculating the text flow.

Comment: Maybe the table which gets moved to a new page is set to disallow page breaks; go to Table › Format › Text Flow to check. Maybe all the paragraphs in the cells table which gets moved to a new page are set to "Keep with next paragraph"; to check, select all the table and go to Format › Paragraph › Text Flow and clear the checkbox "Keep with next paragraph".

Comment: @vanadium (I so like your username), indeed, it seemed to have gone away upwards. An answer dealing with should be good (especially combined with what AlexP said).

Comment: It is easy to run into this problem when using "split table" on a table that has the "text flow -> break page" property set. Unexpectedly (for me), the split table inherits this property, and therefore jumps to the next page after split (at least in LO 6.4.7.2). It would be much easier to force a page break manually after the split than to figure out how to undo the inherited break.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue you see with the spacing is likely temporary, and likely related to a Libreoffice issue in automatic text flow. Likely the gap will be gone if you close and reopen the document, or if you do some action that require Libreoffice to recalcalculate the text flow. I also had this experience.

User AlexP mentioned two formatting options that actually may cause a table to be moved to another page.

- The table which gets moved to a new page may be set to disallow page breaks; check this by going to "Table › Format › Text Flow".
- The paragraphs in the cells of the table that gets moved to a new page may be set to "Keep with next paragraph"; to check, select the entire table, go to "Format › Paragraph › Text Flow" and verify that the checkbox "Keep with next paragraph" is cleared.

To merge the two tables you pasted, place the cursor between the two tables and press the <kbd>Delete</kbd> key to remove the space. Then place the cursor in the lower table, and select "Table > Merge Table" to actually merge the two tables into one.

Comment: I  think it's worth adding what AlexP said as well just in case it gets deleted in the future...

Comment: Since this came with a huge bonus, I feel I should be fully at your service here ;-) Indeed, it is useful to check other possibilities why a next table may be kept together on a next page.